# Replace each character of a word with line break

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, regex

I want to have a line break between each character/letter of the word

if the word is 
     < Hello >
I want it as

```
 H

 e

 l

 l

 o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.`
- Replace with: `$0\n`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.           # any character but linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match, a single character
\n          # a line feed, you can use \r\n for Windows end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I think the OP should accept your answer for its simplicity. I also learn that it is possible to use $0 with Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then set:

1. Find what: `([\w\s\d])>`
2. Replace with: `$1\n`
3. Set search mode to Regular expression

Example:

```
Welcome < Hello > world
```

Output:

```
W
e
l
o
c
m
e

< 
H
e
l
l
o

> 
w
o
r
d
```

Comment: Thanks Reddy, thats only for Hello word..This wont work for me... I have a string with 365-366 characters in it, and I want it in vertical format, please !

Comment: @Hytool See edit